# Remover objeto com o tempo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom, tenho o seguinte modal

```
<div id="alerta-imagem">
    As imagens de perfil precisam ter altura e largura proporcionais, com tamanho máximo de 200x200
</div>
```

Procurei no google algumas formas, mas só encontrei o `setTimeOut()` e `setInterval()`, mas não consegui usá-los, queria saber tanto com `javascript` tanto com `jquery`, como faço para que, por exemplo, após 10 segundos este modal ganhe um `display:none`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o setTimeout junto com o hide do jquery, segue o exemplo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="modal"> Testeeeeeee </div>

<script>
 
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#modal').hide();  

  }, 3*1000); // 3 segundos
 
</script>
```

Comment: perfeito, obrigado :3